# JavaFX Label an Axis in 3D

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

[So I have this scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8EZE.jpg)

The Axes are just JavaFX Boxes that I created to represent the axes.

How would I label the axes? I've tried using JavaFX Label and Text objects but they just display in 2D, but I may be using them wrong. Is there some way to label (e.g. put the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 along the axes) these axes in 3D?

Answer (score 1):

We've added a Floating Label example to fxyz3d.org... check out the sample:
[FloatingLabels.java](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/Fxyz-Samples/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/samples/utilities/FloatingLabels.java)

To generically manage 2D labels connected to a Point3D you need to do a transform along the following:

```
        Point3D coordinates = node.localToScene(javafx.geometry.Point3D.ZERO);
        SubScene oldSubScene = NodeHelper.getSubScene(node);
        coordinates = SceneUtils.subSceneToScene(oldSubScene, coordinates);
        double x = coordinates.getX();
        double y = coordinates.getY();
        label.getTransforms().setAll(new Translate(x, y));
```

There are other details you have to worry about like properly adding to the subscene and clipping but those are included in the example.